# Labeling Sets of Binary Values with Custom Names

Tags: r

I have a table of users who have about 5 attribute sets (age, gender, household income, occupation, state). For each attribute, there is a binary assignment (i.e. 1 if they have the attribute, 0 if they don't.

Example:

```
Index   Female   Male   Age 18-34   Age 35-64   Age 65+
1       1      0        1           0           0
2       1      0        0           1           0
3       0      1        1           0           0
```

I then utilized interaction function to create an interaction variable for each attribute set, and although it gives the right output, it's not ideal:

Formula:

```
data$GENDER <- with(data, interaction(data$Female, data$Male, sep=""))
```

Output:

```
Index   Gender
1       10
2       10
3       01
```

Ideally I'd like something like:

```
Index   Gender
1       F
2       F
3       M
```

Is there an easy way to do this without having to classify each interaction variable value (i.e. 10 = F, 01 = M)?

Thanks in advance,

Stu

Comment: Worked a charm BUT one of my variables is State which means I have 52 variables I'd need to define PLUS all the interaction variables - any idea of how to work with this many variables in a similar fashion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little function that I wrote which should be able to handle this nicely and will report `NA` values in the instance of no category selected, or multiple categories selected:

```
pickbin <- function(data) {
  x <- NA
  sel <- rowSums(data) == 1
  x[sel] <- max.col(data,"first")[sel]
  names(data)[x]
}

pickbin(dat[2:3])
#[1] "Female" "Female" "Male"  
pickbin(dat[4:6])
#[1] "Age18_34" "Age35_64" "Age18_34"
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
Index   Female   Male   Age18_34   Age35_64   Age65
1       1      0        1           0           0
2       1      0        0           1           0
3       0      1        1           0           0",header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Better than what I was looking for*

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `pmax`

```
c("F", "M")[do.call(pmax, df1[2:3]*col(df1[2:3]))]
#[1] "F" "F" "M"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mydata<-read.table(header = T, text = "
Index   Female   Male   Age_18-34   Age_35-64   Age_65+
1       1      0        1           0           0
2       1      0        0           1           0
3       0      1        1           0           0")

mydata$Gender<-with(mydata, ifelse(Female ==1, "F" ,ifelse(Male ==1, "M", NA)))
mydata

Index Female Male Age_18.34 Age_35.64 Age_65. Gender
1      1    0         1         0       0      F
2      1    0         0         1       0      F
3      0    1         1         0       0      M
```

Comment: I think this could work, but take, for example, the state variable which has 52 different states - would I just have to do a nested if for each state?

Comment: I did not know there where multiple cases. I just figured your data was a bigger version of the sample. My apologies.